# how to get the specific value from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have tried different ways to get the specific values from a dictionary but couldn't get what I wanted.
Here is my current dictionary:

```
{'email': 'rafae.raza@gmail.com', 'name': 'Rafae Raza', 'password': 'Rafae@123',
 'preferences': {
     'activities': ['Hiking', 'Cycling', 'Trekking', 'Skiing', 'Rock Climbing', 'Para Sailing', 'Camping', 'Boating',
                    'Sight Seeing'],
     'categories': ['Coastal', 'Deserts', 'Forts', 'Hill Stations', 'Islands', 'Lakes'],
     'districts': ['Punjab', 'Sindh', 'Islamabad', 'KPK',
                   'Gilgit-Baltistan', 'Azad Kashmir']}, 'profilePicture': ''}
```

I want to get only the categories' list from this dictionary.
How can I do that?

Here is my code so far assume listt as a dictionary.

```
listt = list(anotherDict.val())

for i in listt:
    if (i == "preferences"):
        print(listt.pop(3))
```

It just prints "preferences"

Comment: Are you only looking to retrieve a value from a dict? (like `anotherDict['preferences']`) Or do you have another problem? It's unclear what all this code is supposed to achieve?

Comment: You can simply use `anotherDict["preferences"]["categories"]`

Comment: Also dictionaries don't have a `.val()` method. Your code won't run at all, let alone print `"preferences"`.

Comment: @jarmod that's great trick. thank you to let us know

Comment: This is the standard way to access data in embedded dictionaries. You should use this approach rather than iterating over the items in the dict, searching by key. The whole point of using a dict is so that you get constant time access to items (as opposed to a list, which requires you to iterate over the items in linear time).

Answer (score 0):

When you put listt = list(//something) the dictionary of listt becomes with only keys. so remove the line `listt = list(anotherDict.val())`
You can get the values of nested items in dictionary by the following code.

```
listt = //your dictionary
for i in listt:
    if (i == "preferences"):
        print(listt[i]['categories'])
```